# How to render multiple videos on a sphere using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, video.js

Three.js is new to me, so I am a bit stuck on this.

I read the answer to this question: [Using multiuple textures on a sphere [Three.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350251/using-multiuple-textures-on-a-sphere-three-js)

The answer suggests the user to use a cube to load the textures on, instead of sphere.That being done, the cube can be expanded to a sphere.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8 );
for ( var i in geometry.vertices ) {
    var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
    vertex.normalize().multiplyScalar(radius);
}

var materialArray = [];
var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: sphereColor,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.4
});
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    materialArray.push(faceMaterial);
}

var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );
```

Will the same thing work for videos? If I wish to play six videos on a sphere, should I load the 'video' texture onto the six faces of the cube and then expand it to a sphere.

EDIT:

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>three.js webgl - equirectangular video panorama</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #info {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; width: 100%;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family:Monospace;
            font-size:13px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align:center;
        }

        a {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="three.js"></script>

    <script>

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var texture_placeholder,
        isUserInteracting = false,
        onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
        lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
        lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
        phi = 0, theta = 0,
        distance = 500;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            var container, mesh;

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //var geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
            //geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1,1,1,32,32,32 );
            geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );
            for ( var i in geometry.vertices ) {
                    var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
                vertex.normalize().multiplyScalar(distance);
            }

            //var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
            //video.width = 640;
            //video.height = 360;
            //video.autoplay = true;
            //video.loop = true;
            //video.src = "pano.webm";


            var path = "vids/";
            var format = '.mp4';
            var urls = [
                    path + 'Row1Col1' + format, path + 'Row1Col2' + format,
                    path + 'Row1Col3' + format, path + 'Row2Col1' + format,
                    path + 'Row2Col2' + format, path + 'Row2Col3' + format
                ];

            var reflectionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
            reflectionCube.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            reflectionCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

            //var texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
            //texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
            //texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

            //var material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : texture } );

            //mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            //scene.add( mesh );

            var materialArray = [];
            var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    color: 0xffff00,
                    transparent: true,
                    opacity: 0.4
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    materialArray.push(faceMaterial);
            }

            var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);
            var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( sphere );

            //End of what I have added

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onDocumentMouseWheel, false);

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            isUserInteracting = true;

            onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
            onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

            onPointerDownLon = lon;
            onPointerDownLat = lat;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {

                lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
                lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            isUserInteracting = false;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

            // WebKit

            if ( event.wheelDeltaY ) {

                distance -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;

            // Opera / Explorer 9

            } else if ( event.wheelDelta ) {

                distance -= event.wheelDelta * 0.05;

            // Firefox

            } else if ( event.detail ) {

                distance += event.detail * 1.0;

            }

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            update();

        }

        function update() {

            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

            camera.position.x = distance * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            camera.position.y = distance * Math.cos( phi );
            camera.position.z = distance * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.lookAt( camera.target );

            /*
            // distortion
            camera.position.copy( camera.target ).negate();
            */

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>
</body>
```

However, it does not work. After I host it on the web there's just a black screen. Can you tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Presumably that's how you can do it, yes.

Comment: The materialArray should have the paths to my videos, right?

Comment: I don't know. Can you display a video on anything else that way (like a square)?

Comment: @immibis Check [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_youtube)

Comment: Please have a look at my implementation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have any error in console or network tab from your Web Developper Toolkit (F12 key for almost all browsers)

Comment: @Alex I checked the console and network tab, they show no error...

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of my recent findings working with 360 videos in threejs (I am also new to threejs), you could be seeing the black screen due to the overall resolution being too high. If each video is at 4k resolution, then you are trying to display a 24k res video. I start encountering issues where I get black screen after 5.7k, even on higher end equipment and 100+ mbps network speeds.