# Is there a built-in way to layer textures within the standard PBR shader?

Tags: three.js

I want to have an effect similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287547/multiple-transparent-textures-on-the-same-mesh-face-in-three-js?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), in Aframe, to have layered swappable textures on a single model:

I am wondering if there is a standard process I have missed in Threejs so that I can *continue to use the standard shader*; or do I have to fork it and add the multi-texture capability myself in a custom shader?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12135) what you mean?

Comment: Could you combine the textures on a canvas and use that as your texture like [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/e6rbt3r4/)?

Comment: These are both great solutions. Thank you. I think the groups is probably more along the lines of what I am looking for (multiple materials) but I love the simplicity off the canvas decal system. Thanks both!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to layer materials or textures using three.js.

Here is a pattern that currently works:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
geometry.clearGroups();
geometry.addGroup( 0, Infinity, 0 );
geometry.addGroup( 0, Infinity, 1 );
geometry.addGroup( 0, Infinity, 2 );
geometry.addGroup( 0, Infinity, 3 );

var materials = [ material0, material1, material2, material3 ];

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
scene.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.144

Comment: You said you can do this to layer materials or textures. How would you do this with textures?

Comment: @cmomoney You set `material0.map = texture0; material1.map = texture1`;

Comment: For others attempting to use this method while also using a raycaster (e.g. `const intersectsModels = raycaster.intersectObjects(objectScene.children, true);`): add a finite number for the second parameter, else your script will hang!

Even something big like this will work:
`geometry.addGroup( 0, 50000, 0 );
geometry.addGroup( 0, 50000, 1 );`

Comment: It would appear that this is unsupported in three.js as of 4/2023, or am I missing something?  The documentation explicity states:  "Every vertex and index must belong to exactly one group — groups must not share vertices or indices, and must not leave vertices or indices unused."

Comment: @GerhardWesp Certain operations like merging groups may no longer work as expected. Did you try the suggestion on a recent release?