# Apply a material over an existing one

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm trying to add a texture to the 3d object, but if the object has a material with a white background I can see the texture correctly, while if the object is dark or transparent the texture becomes dark or transparent like the object.
I can't find a way to solve this problem, I thought of applying another material over the object but I don't see how it is possible.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49702885/1461008

Comment: By applying a material over an existing one you mean replacing the old material right?

Comment: no we don't wanna replace the old material, but just apply new img on top when in the screenshot